# C#: Elegant way to wrap method calls

Tags: c#, decorator, func

Apologies for the fairly ambiguous title but what I'm trying to achieve is probably better stated in code.

I have a WCF client. When I'm calling methods I would like to wrap each call in some error handling code. So, instead of exposing the methods directly, I've created the following helper function on the client class:

```
    public T HandleServiceCall<T>(Func<IApplicationService, T> serviceMethod)
    {
        try
        {
            return serviceMethod(decorator);
        }
        [...]
    }
```

And the client code uses it like this:

```
service.HandleServiceCall(channel => channel.Ping("Hello"));
```

And the call to Ping gets nicely wrapped in some logic that will try to handle any errors.

This works great except that I now have a requirement to know which methods are actually being called on the service. Initially , I was hoping to just inspect the `Func<IApplicationService, T>` using Expression trees but didn't get very far.

Finally, I settled on a Decorator pattern:

```
    public T HandleServiceCall<T>(Func<IApplicationService, T> serviceMethod)
    {
        var decorator = new ServiceCallDecorator(client.ServiceChannel);
        try
        {
            return serviceMethod(decorator);
        }
        [...]
        finally
        {
            if (decorator.PingWasCalled)
            {
                Console.Writeline("I know that Ping was called")
            }
        }
    }
```

And the Decorator itself:

```
    private class ServiceCallDecorator : IApplicationService
    {
        private readonly IApplicationService service;

        public ServiceCallDecorator(IApplicationService service)
        {
            this.service = service;
            this.PingWasCalled = new Nullable<bool>();
        }

        public bool? PingWasCalled
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public ServiceResponse<bool> Ping(string message)
        {
            PingWasCalled = true;
            return service.Ping(message);
        }
    }
```

It's really clunky and quite a lot of code. *Is there a more elegant way of doing this?*

Comment: Where do you create the decorator?

Comment: Expression trees should be the way to go. Can you show the code and tell us what the problem was?

Comment: Sounds like a job for PostSharp.

Comment: @smartcaveman: It's a private class in the same parent class as `HandleServiceMethod`

Comment: @Daniel: That's what I tried first but failed at the first hurdle - Converting a `Func` to and `Expression`.

Comment: @geofftnz: Whilst I feel my dectorator solution is too much code, I think that something like PostSharp would be a little overkill. Is there a solution native to C#? Or a free alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an Expression, then inspect the body.

Something like

```
public T HandleServiceCall<T>(Expression<Func<IApplicationService, T>> serviceMethod)     
{         
    try         
    {          
        var func = serviceMethod.Compile();
        string body = serviceMethod.Body.ToString();
        return func(new ConcreteAppService()); 
    }        
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ...     
              }
}
```

Comment: This, combined with @Enrico's description of how to inspect the method call works out well. It also incidentally solves another issues because it prevents the client entering more than a single method call - which is a nice addition.

Comment: My final solution is a combination of answers given by @Richard Friend and @Enrico Campidoglio, where I used Enrico's code to identify the method being called.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using aspect oriented approach? It sounds like exactly what you need.

Wrapping exceptions and other 'meta method' functionality could be written as aspects 'orthogonal' to what your serviceMethods do.

Some general information on AOP: [AOP in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

And a potential solution with a container: [AOP with Windsor Castle](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx)

Comment: I agree, this fits well. To me it feels a little overkill. Is there a simpler, native alternative?

Comment: a more lightweight version could be the (suggested above) PostSharp. I haven't used it though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example using an **expression tree**:

```
public T HandleServiceCall<T>(Expression<Func<T>> serviceMethod)
{
    try
    {
        return serviceMethod();
    }
    finally
    {
        var serviceMethodInfo = ((MethodCallExpression)serviceMethod.Body).Method;
        Console.WriteLine("The '{0}' service method was called", serviceMethodInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

Note that this example assumes that the `serviceMethod` expression always contains a method invocation.

**Related resources:**

- [Expression Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx)
- [MethodCallExpression Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.aspx)

Comment: And only one method invocation?

Comment: Trying to test this out but Func does not contain a definition for Body.

Comment: You need to change the type of the argument of the `HandleServiceCall<T>` method to `Expression<Func<T>>`

Comment: The lambda expression you pass to the `Expression<Func<T>>` parameter cannot contain multiple statements or you will get a compiler error, since it cannot be converted to an expression tree ("_A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree_").

Comment: I've combined your answer with @Richard's and as you suggest, used Expression<Func> as the arguement. Your second point about multiple statements is actually beneficial to me because it restricts the client to calling only one method at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe your code is overcooked.

In terms of Wrapping your code for a common safe disposing of proxies, look [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html) for a nice implementation. Using it is easy:

```
using (var client = new Proxy().Wrap()) {
 client.BaseObject.SomeMethod();
}
```

Now you also need to access method name - for that simply use `Environment.StackTrace`. You need to add walking up the stack in Marc Gravell's `Wrap`.

Comment: This approach is slightly different to the way I have designed my code. If I were to do some heavy refactoring I would definitely consider this.